# webpack - split chunks

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-splitchunks

Webpack 4+ already comes with [`optimisation`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) out of the box.

There is still one unclear thing to me:

#### Does deduplication happen across dependencies?

example:

```
/node_modules/foo has a bundled dependency 'foobar'
```

but also

```
/node_modules/bar has a bundled dependency 'foobar'
```

**does webpack dedupe the `foobar` dependency when I import both into my main bundle?**

```
import foo from 'foo';
import baz from 'baz';

foo(baz('hello world'));
```

I would say it doesn't, since those packages come already bundled, but I couldn't find any official documentation about it...

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the imports from `foo` & `bar` are imports to a **module** foobar, then this module become a part of the deps tree of you app, therefore it will be only once at the tree.

If `foo` & `bar` has a copy of the code, webpack will not able to "identify" that code as duplicated and won't be able to keep only one copy.